# MySQL ошибка добавления данных

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-key

имеется таблицы price и product.
В таблице price имеется поле product_id, по которому связываются эти таблицы.

При добавлении записей в product, выдает ошибку:

> 1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`project`.`product`, CONSTRAINT `lnk_product_price` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `price` (`product_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)')

Мне нужно в любой момент времени добавлять новые данные в таблицу, или обновлять. Как можно исправить?

В `ON DELETE` и `ON UPDATE` на что лучше `CASCADE` изменить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно объявили внешний ключ. Его нужно объявлять не в таблице `product`, а в таблице `price`

```
ALTER TABLE price ADD
  CONSTRAINT `lnk_product_price` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`id`)
     ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Чтобы удалить данные из таблицы product нужно будет удалить связь эту? Просто данные в таблице product есть, а в price нет, и не дает удалить данные

Comment: При таком ключе как у вас сейчас данных в product быть не может. Текущий ключ удаляйте. Он не верен в принципе. После добавления моего ключа, при удалении записей из `product` записи из `price` удалятся каскадно

Comment: Я имел в виду ваш ключ. Именно при нем я не могу выполнить команду TRUNCATE к таблицу product

Comment: Логично. TRUNCАТЕ не проверяет ссылочную целостность. Выполните `DELETE FROM product`